# MIME body containing attachment image asks for password in SSO environment

Tags: lotus-notes, mime-message

Application sends memo to Notes users in MIME format. Content is generated from HTML rendering of RT Body field in background agent. Body contains attachment of type .LOG. Attachment image uses image associated with filetype based on user's (who modified original document) environment, Notepad icon in this case. IMG source for attachment image goes to Domino server configured to use SPNEGO SSO authentication (agent rendered the Body on that server).

```
<img width="203" height="34" alt="filename.log" border="0" src="https://server/appl/app.nsf/viewunid/docunid/Body/0.5FA?OpenElement&FieldElemFormat=gif"/>
```

When user opens mail in Notes client, image is not rendered and user is prompted to enter credentials. After several attempts it fails and image is not visible. But, if user opens website with IE browser just before opening the memo, credentials are not required and image shows with no problem.

It seems that internal browser in Notes client is not able to negotiate/initialize SSO session with server.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Notes client supports SPNEGO authentication, so I think you're going to have to embed the images almong the your HTML within a multipart/related MIME entity in the message, set the Content-ID header for the image entity and use "cid:" URLs in the src attribute.